# Java: Most efficient way to convert an throwable/exception's entire stack trace into a ByteBuffer?

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace, throwable

What is the most efficient method to convert an throwable/exception's entire stack trace into a ByteBuffer (in Java)?

Specifically, I need to log the entire exception into the database. The Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() returns a list of StackTraceElement[] array.

Then, there is a printStackTrace() method in Throwable class?

Comment: You just *don't* use exception-throwing code where performance is significant. Getting and formatting the stack trace is not very efficient anyway.

Comment: @gpeche - I don't think avoiding Exceptions altogether is a good suggestion. It may not even be an option if dealing with third-party libs. Even if your code is slow and performance is a concern, there are probably a million other things to profile and optimize first before considering to stop using Exceptions. They may be slow but not _that_ slow.

Comment: @Jesse Webb In fact I prefer exception handling to the alternatives, it's just that "the most efficient method to convert an throwable/exception's entire stack trace into a ByteBuffer" does not make much sense to me. A bit like asking about the most efficient method to write to `System.out`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to do that, this should be what you need:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ex.printStackTrace(new PrintStream(os));
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(os.toByteArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ExceptionUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.html) class in apache commons.

Comment: Specifically, the `getFullStackTrace()` method should be used. It includes the stack of any nested Exceptions while the `getStackTrace()` method does not. It returns a String, which can easily be turned into bytes. http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#getFullStackTrace%28java.lang.Throwable%29